# How to disable management function (telnet, http) for Cisco 3750 on Interfaces?

Tags: switch

How can I disable the management functions on interfaces 2 to 24 and enable the management functions on interface 1 (fa 0/1) on my Cisco Catalyst 3750, is there a Thread or Tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a management vlan and put only interface 1 in that managment vlan. If you search for creating a management vlan you will find plenty of information. By default vlan1 is the management vlan and Cisco (and everyone) recommends that you change it to something other than default (any number other than 1). Also, it is recommended that you use SSH rather than telnet so transmissions, including usernames and passwords, are not transmitted in plain-text.

Here is one link that demonstrates creating a management vlan: http://www.freeccnaworkbook.com/workbooks/ccna/configuring-a-management-vlan-interface/

Otherwise, if you have a set of IP addresses that you want to give management access to, you could just use access lists that allow the desired management protocols (ssh/telnet, http: *see below) from only those addresses. 
http://www.omnisecu.com/cisco-certified-network-associate-ccna/how-to-create-and-configure-access-control-lists-for-vty-lines-telnet-ssh.htm

Conversely, you could apply access lists to all interfaces except int1 that block all telnet/ssh connections. You would also need to block access to the port that the web interface uses. *Since that is 80 by default you will need to change the web management interface to a different port ( http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps663/products_tech_note09186a0080094156.shtml#cfg_port ). If you do not change the management interface to a different port (leave it at 80) and block port 80, you will obviously have no http access at all.